# Use a user generated function to sort 2 columns of a data frame such that 1 column has values that are smaller than the corresponding column

Tags: r, function

I wan to use a user generated function to sort 2 columns of a data frame such that 1 column has values that are smaller than the corresponding column.

For example, here is the starting dataset:

```
# base dataset
numerical_values_dataset_start <- 
  data.frame(
    A = c("0.798963315", "0.160710819", "0.247170125", "-0.910092611", "0.42959469", "0.710921651", "0.160710819"),
    B = c("0.321418973", "0.710921651", "0.910092611", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.160710819"),
    C = c("0.812661261", "0.146377668", "0.42959469", "0.710921651", "0.710921651", "0.710921651", "0.160710819")
  )
```

Here is the desired column:

```
# desired dataset
numerical_values_dataset_end <- 
  data.frame(
    A = c("0.798963315", "0.160710819", "0.247170125", "-0.910092611", "0.42959469", "0.710921651", "0.160710819"),
    B = c("0.321418973", "0.146377668", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.42959469", "0.160710819"),
    C = c("0.812661261", "0.710921651", "0.910092611", "0.710921651", "0.710921651", "0.710921651", "0.160710819")
  )
```

Essentially, I want the rows associated with columns `B` and `C` of the dataset to be set so that the smaller value is in column `B` and the larger value is in column `C`. I also want to be able to modify the code so that I can change the dataset used by the function. I tried to make the function myself, but it doesn't work.

```
function_range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting <- 
  # ---- NOTE: changes whole dataset
  # ---- NOTE: lower_value == lower value in range being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: upper_value == lower value in range being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: dataset_name == data set being evaluated
  # ---- NOTE: function_range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting == function name
  function(upper_value, lower_value, dataset_name)
  {
    # ---- NOTE: # turns dataset into data frame
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object <- 
      data.frame(
        cbind(
          names(lower_value) = lower_value,
          names(upper_value) = upper_value
        )
      )
    # ---- NOTE: # transforms values of interest into numeric form
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$test_value <- as.numeric(as.character(range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$test_value))
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value <- as.numeric(as.character(range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value))
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value <- as.numeric(as.character(range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value))
    # ---- NOTE: # sets data so lower_value <= upper_value
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates storage variables
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage <- range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage <- range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates upper_value
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value <- 
      ifelse(((range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage) > (range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage)), range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage,
             ifelse(((range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage) < (range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage)), range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage,
                    ifelse(((range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage) == (range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage)), range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage,
                           NA
                    )))
    # ---- NOTE: ## creates lower_value
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value <- 
      ifelse(((range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage) > (range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage)), range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage,
             ifelse(((range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage) < (range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage)), range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage,
                    ifelse(((range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper_value_storage) == (range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage)), range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value_storage,
                           NA
                    )))
    # ---- NOTE: creates range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_2 object 2 containing dataset_name
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_2 <- data.frame(dataset_name)
    # ---- NOTE: removes specific columns in range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_2
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_3 <- data.frame(subset(range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_2, select = -c(colnames(range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object))))
    # ---- NOTE: binds upper and lower values to dataset of interest
    range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_4 <- 
      data.frame(
        cbind(
          range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_3,
          range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$lower_value,
          range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object$upper value
        )
      )
    # ---- NOTE: returns appropriate object
    return(range_upper_and_lower_limit_dataset_setting_funct_object_4)
  }
```

Is this possible? Can I use the function that I already created to do this? Is there some other method that can be used to accomplish this task?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values rowwise for all the columns except `A` :

```
numerical_values_dataset_start <- type.convert(numerical_values_dataset_start, as.is = TRUE)
numerical_values_dataset_start[-1] <- t(apply(numerical_values_dataset_start[-1], 1, sort))
numerical_values_dataset_start

#           A         B         C
#1  0.7989633 0.3214190 0.8126613
#2  0.1607108 0.1463777 0.7109217
#3  0.2471701 0.4295947 0.9100926
#4 -0.9100926 0.4295947 0.7109217
#5  0.4295947 0.4295947 0.7109217
#6  0.7109217 0.4295947 0.7109217
#7  0.1607108 0.1607108 0.1607108
```

The numbers are stored as strings. I used `type.convert` to convert them to actual numbers.